# How to prove $\sum_p {1 \over p^s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\mu(n) \over n} \log \zeta(ns)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

## Problem

Prove that for $\operatorname{Re}(s)> 0$,
$$
\sum_p {1 \over p^s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\mu(n) \over n} \log \zeta(ns),
$$
where the sum extends over all primes $p$.

Notes: $\log$ is natural, $\mu$ is the Möbius $\mu$ function, $\zeta$ is the Riemann $\zeta$ function.

## Progress

Using the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$ on the right-hand side gives
$$
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\mu(n)} \sum_p \log (1-p^{-ns}) = -\sum_p \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\mu(n) \over n} \log(1-p^{-ns}).
$$
Equating the terms of this sum with the desired left-hand side would be
$$
{1 \over p^s} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\mu(n) \over n} \log(1-p^{-ns}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\mu(n) \over n} \sum_{m=1}^\infty {1 \over m} p^{-mns},
$$
where the Taylor series for $\log(1-x^{-1})$ was used for the second equality. This is the only way I can see to introduce sum over the primes on the right-hand side. Based on some numerical tests in Mathematica, I haven't made a mistake thus far, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: only for $Re(s) > 1$

Comment: For reference: this is the prime zeta function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After that last step, you need to use
$$ \sum_{d\setminus n} \mu(d) = [n=1], $$
(e.g., [(18) in mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html); I also used [the Iverson bracket](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IversonBracket.html)), and rewrite the sum as a sum over integers $mn$ and their divisors $n$:
$$ \sum_{n,m\geq1} \frac{\mu(n)}{mn}p^{-mns} = \sum_{k,n\geq1} \frac{p^{-ks}}{k}\mu(n)[n\setminus k] = \sum_{k\geq1}\frac{p^{-ks}}{k}[k=1]. $$
This is a common trick for this sort of thing.

Comment: Is this property of the Möbius function something commonly taught in elementary number theory courses?

Comment: @DanielH. I believe it is, right next to the [Moebius inversion formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusInversionFormula.html).